# How to use JSON without json file?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to use dynamically JSON with data.TreeStore.
With this component, there is proxy "config", it need a path to JSON file.
My problem is, i can't write Json file in my application.
I would know, if i can generated JSON dynamically and pass it to url config into proxy?

For example :

```
Var trStore = Ext.create('Ext.Data.TreeStore',{

... // config
proxy {

type : 'ajax',
url : { id : 'id0', task :'task0', value : 'val0', ..... }

}
});
```

My URL is not a file url but is JSON generated with my own method !

How to build JSON for use it with TreeStore and without make file !?

I hope you understand my problem :)

Thanks a lot to help !

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks like you want to pass static "inline data" to the TreeStore.

As far as I can see this is not possible with a bare TreeStore, since it does not have a *data* config option as the "normal" Store has. However, it is possible with a Treepanel.

You can pass your inline data to the TreeStore using the *root* config option of the Treepanel (not the TreeStore). It works in a very similar manner as the *data* config option of a "normal" Store:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
  root: { id : 'id0', task :'task0', value : 'val0', children: [...], ... }
  // ...
});
```

There are two caveats related to this:

- The beta3 docs say *root* is boolean, that's wrong.
- Because of a bug in beta3 you cannot use this together with *rootVisible: false*.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a "json file" is really just a text string, so you can generate that with PHP or your preferred server software.

For the url in the proxy, simply put in the url you use to run that function. Eg in my web app I have `http://example.org/controller/getTree?output=json`

This runs the `getTree()` function on my `controller`, and the function knows to return json.